# How to grep for the exact word if the string has got dot in it

Tags: linux, bash

I was trying to search for a particular word `BML.I` in a current directory.

When I tried with the below command:

```
grep -l  "BML.I" *
```

It is displaying all the results if it contains  the word `BML`

Is it possible to grep for the exact match `BML.I`

Comment: Are you looking for file names or file content?

Comment: @Alepac obviously he's looking for content.

Comment: Just read `man grep`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to escape the . (period) since by default it matches against any character, and specify -w to match a specific word e.g.

```
grep -w -l "BML\.I" *
```

Note there are two levels of escaping in the above. The quotes ensure that the shell passes `BML\.I` to grep. The `\` then escapes the period for `grep`. If you omit the quotes, then the shell interprets the `\` as an escape for the period (and would simply pass the unescaped period to `grep`)

Comment: You might want single quotes there.

Comment: I *might* do, but there are no variables to interpret/expand in the expression

Comment: this will match `fooBML.Ibar` which is not a `particular word "BML.I"`

Comment: @Kent - ah. Didn't read the question properly. Now amended. Thx

Answer (score 10):

try `grep -wF`

from man page:

```
 -w, --word-regexp
                  Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words.  The
                  test is that the matching substring must either be at  the  beginning  of
                  the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it
                  must be either at  the  end  of  the  line  or  followed  by  a  non-word
                  constituent  character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits,
                  and the underscore.



 -F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret  PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any
              of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `fgrep`, which is the same as `grep -F`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

`ls | grep -x "BML.I"`