# How to delete folders not in list of folders?

Tags: git, shell

i'm working with jenkins/git and i want to clean my directory (/var/www/branches/) from old git branches this branches are represented as folders in a different directory ( a part from my git repository), what i do is that i retrieve current working branches put them in a file using the command :

`listBranchRemote=$(git --git-dir=$gitDirectory/.git branch -qr |cut -d'/' -f 2,3 | tee -a branch.txt` )

the `branch.txt` represents the only folders that should be kept in /var/www/branches/ directory. How to delete folders not in my file that i created.

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:batch-file]? read the tag info!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a similar process than "[How to iterate through all git branches using bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847586/6309)", except you would need to:

- select only local branches:

  ```
  git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads/|cut -d'/' -f 3,4
  ```
- [grep the local branch name with `branch.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521695/6309)

  ```
  if ! grep -w -l "${abranch_name}" branch.txt; then ... delete; fi
  ```

Comment: iterating over local branches needs to be done in my git repository, but as i said i only have representation of these branches as folder in another directory a part from my local git repository

Comment: @AILY Branches are not directory in Git. Can you edit your question to illustrate what those "branches" are in your own workspace?

Comment: @AILY If you had cloned/checkout branches in their own folder in `/var/www/branches/`directly, you can delete those subfolder: the `then ... delete` part of my answer becomes `rm -Rf /var/www/branches/abranch_name`.